# How to publish in ethereum with "imports" ? or how to do?

Tags: solidity, compiler, verify, deployed-bytecode

Hello i have this question in my mind now :

> How to publish in ethereum with "imports" ? or how to do ?

why i say this ?

answer : when i wanna "verify and publish Contract Source Code" with a normal code without "import" the verify is successful

the problem : but when i try to do the same with a code has a "import" in the code , the "verify" fails and say me this error

```
Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (Compiler Exception)
```

the abi is fine but i think they cant generate the bytecode for this warnning :

```
myc:9:1: ParserError: Source "MyToken.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import './MyToken.sol'
^-------------------------^
```

i trying to solving but nothing works for me and i don't know what i need to read to solve this problem and publish my contract, if somebody have documentation for solve this problem please help me

i am searching that  errors but i don't see information to how solve them

here is a example of the running code

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import './MyToken.sol';

contract test1 {

    /* Variables */
    MyToken isMyToken;

    /* Constructor to define things */
    constructor(MyToken _myToken) public {

        isMyToken = _myToken;

    }


}
```

thanks a lot for read

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan has introduced some multifile methods that might help with this.

The good old-fashioned method is to create a flat version of the contract for verification purposes. That can be done manually or with the help of a utility (google Solidity Flattener).

A flat version would be a single file Test1.sol where you remove the `import` and simply append the source code of `MyToken.sol` in the same file. It compiles to the same bytecode, which is what the verifier is trying to confirm.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Truffle-Flattener.**

In your `package.json` file, add this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "truffle-flattener": "1.4.2"
  }
```

Then, run the following NodeJS script passing your file name (without `.sol`) as input:

```
const WORK_DIR = "<YourProjectDir>";   // Fill your project's directory here
const NODE_DIR = "<node_modules Dir>"; // Fill your node_module directory here
const CONTRACT_NAME = process.argv[2];

const fs        = require("fs");
const path      = require("path");
const spawnSync = require("child_process").spawnSync;

function getPathNames(dirName) {
    let pathNames = [];
    for (const fileName of fs.readdirSync(WORK_DIR + "/" + dirName)) {
        if (fs.statSync(WORK_DIR + "/" + dirName + "/" + fileName).isDirectory())
            pathNames = pathNames.concat(getPathNames(dirName + "/" + fileName));
        else if (fileName.endsWith(".sol"))
            pathNames.push(dirName + "/" + fileName);
    }
    return pathNames;
}

function getSourceCode(pathName) {
    const result = spawnSync("node", [NODE_DIR + "/truffle-flattener/index.js", pathName], {cwd: WORK_DIR});
    return result.output.toString().slice(1, -1);
}

for (const pathName of getPathNames("contracts")) {
    const contractName = path.basename(pathName, ".sol");
    if (CONTRACT_NAME == contractName)
        console.log(getSourceCode(pathName))
}
```